# Suggest Local Application to test SAML authentication with idp as SP initiated

Tags: saml, service-provider, idp, oam

I am looking for local open source application which can run in my local environment which supports SAML authentication. To test my idp as SP initiated authentication.

So, I need a SP application in which I can import my idp metadata to test.

Please suggest open source application to achieve that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of [SAML stacks](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) here that you could use.